# How do I get away from Wind Waker's Big Octo without boomerang, arrows, bombs?

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

When at sea, and trapped in a Big Octo's swirling watery clutches, how do I get away? I don't have the boomerang, bombs or the bow and arrow yet. I have the grappling hook, but I can't seem to use it from the boat.
The only option I figured out myself is just waiting for it to gobble me up, but it takes too long! I'm inpatient!
I'm currently playing the HD version, but I think it's the same as in the original.

Comment: Uhm, a game over?

Comment: And how would I pull that off?

Comment: Save and reload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't.** At this point in the game, as you have correctly observed, you have no way to kill it. Aside from killing it, the only way to get away from a Big Octo is the Ballad of Gales warp song, which, without arrows, you also do not have at this point in the game.

Big Octos only appear in certain sectors. My advice is to avoid those sectors for now, if you can, or, whatever you do, watch out for huge flocks of seagulls. That's your first sign that there is a Big Octo in the area. Stay away, until you have a ranged weapon to kill it with (boomerang is the easiest, and the first one you will get).

Comment: Also: Where are you running into a Big Octo at this point? The game railroads you pretty hard until you get the boomerang if I recall correctly.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see it. C6, Fire Mountain has an 8-eye octo in it. Weird that I have never encountered it at the beginning of the game.

Comment: I encountered it twice in two days, hence this question. :P

Comment: @Protectorone Well, like I said, if you see an abnormally large flock of seagulls at sea, steer clear. At this point in the game, the only thing you can do about big octos is stay away from them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you have to submit to defeat without these particular weapons. Beating the Big Octo for the first time is a crucial part of the game and there is a reason you can only begin to beat it once you've received a certain weapon, and you will realise why soon enough.

Avoid them for the time being until you receive the appropriate weapon to defeat them. :)

Comment: I already finished the game once, but I don't recall ever realizing that… Could you enlighten me?

Comment: @Protectorone: I believe ChrisMoran is referring to the fact that the Boomerang can hit 5 eyes at once. Although I don't see how beating the Big Octo is crucial; they are strictly optional

Comment: The first time I tried killing it with the boomerang I failed. I had to hit the same eye multiple times for it to close. Maybe that's the hero mode effect?

Comment: What he's referring to is the Big Octo in G4, which, when defeated, gives you a larger magic bar, so it is assumed that you have magic going into that fight (which you get shortly before acquiring the first weapon that can take a Big Octo down, the boomerang).